# Q: Error: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts(1068)

Tags: javascript

My code show me this error "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts(1068)

```
class animal {
constructor(especie,edad,color){
    this.especie = especie;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.color = color;
    this.info = `Soy un ${this.especie}, tengo ${this.edad}
    y soy de color ${this.color}`;
}
this.verInfo = ()=>{
    document.write(this.verInfo);
}
```

}

The error show it in **this**.verInfo

Comment: Remove the `this` from `this.verInfo` where you'rve declared it. Why do you have it there ?

Comment: I'm looking a JavaScript course and the guy make like this to declared a method. It also seemed strange to me. Thanks!

Comment: Find a different JavaScript course. If this is part of the example, this course is a waste of time. Also, are you sure you are learning JavaScript right now? The error suggests that you are using `Typescript`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to rewrite it as follows:

Maybe read about classes here. This is a really good reference to start with: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Also you may to rename `animal` as `Animal`.

```
   class Animal {
    constructor(especie,edad,color){
        this.especie = especie;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.color = color;
        this.info = `Soy un ${this.especie}, tengo ${this.edad}
        y soy de color ${this.color}`;
    }
    verInfo = () =>{
        document.write(this.verInfo);
    }
   }
```